# Fastest way to perform BLAST search using a multi-FASTA file against a remote database

Tags: python, biopython, fasta, blast

I have a multi-FASTA file having ~125 protein sequences. I need to perform a BLASTP seach against remote **nr** database. I tried using **NcbiblastpCommandline**, but the issue is that it only accepts files as input. Since my file has a huge number of sequences, I get this error

> ERROR: An error has occurred on the server, [blastsrv4.REAL]:Error: CPU usage limit was
> exceeded, resulting in SIGXCPU (24).

Storing each sequence from the multi-FASTA file to a separate file at a time works, but then the BLAST search becomes tremendoulsy slow (~10 min/query on an average as opposed to ~1 min/query on the NCBI site).

```
blastp_results = []
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline
from Bio import SeqIO
record_iterator = SeqIO.parse("AmpB_DEPs.fasta", "fasta")

for record in record_iterator:
    entry = str(">" + i.description + "\n" + i.seq)
    f1 = open("test.txt", "w")
    f1.write(entry)
    f1.close()
    f2 = open("test.txt", "r")
    blastp_cline = NcbiblastpCommandline(query = 'test.txt', db = 'nr -remote', evalue = 0.05, outfmt = '7 sseqid evalue qcovs pident')
    res = blastp_cline()
    blastp_results.append(res)
    f2.close()
```

I also tried using **NCBIWWW.qblast** but it doesn't seem to provide **Query coverage** information in the output, something which is important for my study.

Can somebody suggest a way to deal with this issue without compromising on search space or default parameters of BLAST? Suggestions on implementing BLAST in other languages such as PERL, R etc. would also be appreciated.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://www.biostars.org/p/493953/